# Issues using selection tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

I'm trying to use the selection tool to cut a logo from a image, without success. The darker parts in the bottom of the logo is a big problem because of the main background color. In addition, the selection tool fails on the border around "2015" also. Is there any way to improve this process? Now i'm just using standard settings in Photoshop.

Here's my image and "2015" is what i'm trying to cut out and create a transparent png-image.

[image]

Comment: Use the pen tool, then convert the path to a selection, or make a vector mask from the path.

Answer (score 5):

As Scott mentioned, you could use the [pen tool](http://www.melissaevans.com/tutorials/how-to-use-photoshops-pen-tool) & convert the [path](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html) to a selection. Or make a [vector mask](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers-vector-masks.html).

These are effective and quick. There is also the option of using the [polygonal lasso tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/polygonal-lasso-tool/) (L) to select the 2,1 and 5 and the [ellipse tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/elliptical-marquee-tool/) (holding SHIFT to make a circular selection) for the 0.

Each time you have a selection of a number I suggest right-clicking it and layering via copy. That way you will wind up with a layer of each number as opposed to trying to clean out the black and not having a layer of your source image.

Also it sounds like the issue you are having at the moment is because either

a) You are using either the [quick selection tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/quick-selection-tool/) or the [magic wand](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/magic-wand-tool/) and have not adjusted the **tolerance** appropriately.

OR

b) you are selecting by colour and therefor all of the black tones in the image are selected as opposed to just the background.

As there are many options to achieve your selection here you may not need to worry about tolerance for this project in particular however I strongly suggest that you consider toggling tolerance in the future to get a feel for it. Tolerance is discussed in the links above for the quick selection and magic wand tools.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The quick selection tool stopped working but if you go to edit-select and mask then the quick selection tool seems to work in their :)

Comment: Hey @tamara! Welcome to GD.SE :) We try to avoid one sentence answers here. Is there any additional information you can add here? Or maybe you can link to an Adobe forum or source for this info? You could even add an image showing the steps you're talking about. Thanks!

Comment: just click (select) at the top menu bar that appears in photoshop and then click select and mask sorry!